# Error Exception in thread while decrypting image

Tags: java

I am getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.crypto.CipherInputStream cannot be cast to javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream

I still can not figure it out. Please give me some advice

```
// Example code showing how to use Java's Password-Based encryption. This
// example is a simplified form of the code in the documentation for the
// java cryptography architecture.
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class sample {
   public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

   // Scanner to read the user's password. The Java cryptography
   // architecture points out that strong passwords in strings is a
   // bad idea, but we'll let it go for this assignment.
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   // Arbitrary salt data, used to make guessing attacks against the
   // password more difficult to pull off.
   byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c,
           (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99 };

   {
     File inputFile = new File("rose.jpg");
      BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
     // Get a password from the user.
     System.out.print("Password: ");
     System.out.flush();
     PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(scanner.nextLine().toCharArray());          
     // Set up other parameters to be used by the password-based
     // encryption.
     PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
     SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
     // Make a PBE Cyhper object and initialize it to encrypt using
     // the given password.
     Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
     pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
     FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg");
     CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(
            output, pbeCipher);
       //File outputFile = new File("image.png");
         ImageIO.write(input,"JPG",cos);
      cos.close();          

   }
   // Now, create a Cipher object to decrypt for us. We are repeating
   // some of the same code here to illustrate how java applications on
   // two different hosts could set up compatible encryption/decryption
   // mechanisms.
   {
      // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      // Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
      // FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("output.jpg");
      // CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fileinput, pbeCipher);
      // BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(cis);


     File inputFile = new File("output.jpg");
     BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
       // Get another (hopefully the same) password from the user.
       System.out.print("Decryption Password: ");
       System.out.flush();
       PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(scanner.next().toCharArray());
       // Set up other parameters to be used by the password-based
       // encryption.
       PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
       SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory
               .getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
       SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
       // Make a PBE Cyper object and initialize it to decrypt using
       // the given password.
       Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
       pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
       // Decrypt the ciphertext and then print it out.
       /*byte[] cleartext = pbeCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
       System.out.println(new String(cleartext));*/
       FileInputStream output = new FileInputStream("output.jpg");
       CipherInputStream cos = new CipherInputStream(
              output, pbeCipher);
        ImageIO.write(input,"JPG",(ImageOutputStream) cos);
        cos.close();

   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your third-to-last line you write:

```
CipherInputStream cos = new CipherInputStream(
          output, pbeCipher);
```

I think it should be:

```
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(
          output, pbeCipher);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is the code that is causing the problem:

```
    FileInputStream output = new FileInputStream("output.jpg");
    CipherInputStream cos = new CipherInputStream(
          output, pbeCipher);
    ImageIO.write(input,"JPG",(ImageOutputStream) cos);
    cos.close();
```

The problem is simple.  You are trying to cast an InputStream (actually a CipherInputStream) to a subtype of OutputStream.  That simply won't work.

If you want to write the image you need to create an output stream chain, not an input stream chain.  If you want to read an image, you shouldn't be using `ImageIO.write` to read it ...

Comment: I changed the last three lines to the following, but now I get   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at sample.main(sample.java:97)                                                                                                             while using the debugger I found:
javax.crypto.CipherInputStream cannot be cast to javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream

Comment: FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\users\\cybernetx\\decrypted_output.jpg");
           CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, pbeCipher);
           ImageIO.write(input,"JPG",cos);
           cos.close();